# What to do when a player wishes for magic not to exist?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

The question is simple, the answer... not so much. My player has access to a wish spell, and he has decided to wish for magic not to exist, on all planes, from the current time, forever. **If I grant his wish, what happens? Can I grant his wish?**

I should note that while I am aware that I can choose for nothing to happen, I do want **something** to happen, even if it is not the intended result.

Comment: There are way too many possible answers to this, and it seems like it will be driven mostly by opinion. This might be a better question to ask on a traditional forum... If you can narrow it down a bit and provide a framework for acceptable answers, that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered other examples of Wish going wrong? If so, why not to use one of them? What was your ideas and why they are not sufficient for you?...

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Perhaps changing the tags to gm-techniques?

Comment: I think the way your PC got his wish can be relevant: a wish granted by an efreet won't work the same as a wish the PC is casting himself.

Comment: maybe we could have a chat about this instead? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58261/wishes-gone-wrong